# Combine Two Tables in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, create-table

I am trying to create a simple CRM. Sadly I am very new to mysql, so I hope you can help me with this Problem:

In the CRM I have two "sibling" tables: country and place. 
Country:

```
CREATE TABLE country
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  country VARCHAR (128),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and Place:

```
CREATE TABLE place
(
  country_id INT (20),
  zip_code VARCHAR (8),
  city VARCHAR (128)
);
```

But I would like to "combine" these to tables. When I put a new entry in the table place, I would like the line "country_id" to be a dropdown menu that contains the primary key id from the table country.

How would I do that?

Comment: sorry, misspelled it in the table place. 
county_id should be country_id

and i would like the IDs from table country to show in the drodown menu

Comment: So basically you need to create a foreign key reference - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

In phpMyAdmin, open the `place` table, then Structure > Relation view. In the foreign key constraints dialog, choose the `country_id` column in the first Column selector. Choose `country` in the table selector, the `id`
 column should appear next to it. Finally click on Save. To test it, ensure you have some countries in the `country` table, then choose the `place` table and Insert: you'll see the dropdown you asked for.